# Returning more than one char * from a method

Tags: c

I want to return more than one char* from a method:

```
char** test1() {
  char **ret = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
  *ret = "aaa";
  *(ret + 1) = "bbb";
  //  *(ret + 2) = "\0"; //needed?
  return ret;
}
```

Do I need `*(ret + 2) = "\0";` Or should it be `*(ret + 2) = NULL;`?

Comment: Either would cause undefined behaviour, because you'd be writing beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: And FWIW, I'd argue that `ret[0] = "aaa"; ret[1] = "bbb";` is a clearer way of writing this.

Comment: Arrays, no matter how you allocate them, don't have any terminator as specified in the C language (with the exception of strings). You might need to add a terminator as part of your own program specification, so you know when the array ends, but then you need to allocate space for that terminator as well.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I changed it to 3. So I don't need NULL?

Comment: Now that you allocate space for a possible terminator, the answer to your question is: It's up to you! Just specify that "this is the array terminator" and go with it, exactly *what* the terminator is doesn't really matter. It can be an empty string (`"\0"` isn't needed, `""` is enough), it can be a `NULL` pointer, or it can be the string `"Foobar"`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, for me `ret[0]` is less comprehensible because `ret` is a double pointer. If it were an array, I'd use `ret[..]`.

Comment: To answer this question it depends on what you're going to do with the array in the calling code. If the calling code wants to find out the length of the array by looking for a termination sentinel, then you need to add a termination sentinel. Otherwise you don't.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are mostly interchangeable, having a pointer to a pointer to a `char` is like having an array of pointers to `char`. Using array indexing syntax usually makes the code more readable, especially since that's how you use `ret`, as an array of strings.

Comment: `ret` points to the first element of an array of 3 elements; those elements are `ret[0]`, `ret[1]`, and `ret[2]`. This is the same whether or not the element type is a pointer type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, `ret points to the first element of an array of 3 elements` - no, it points to a pointer because it's a double pointer, doesn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: In general, if you have `T * p = malloc(N * sizeof(*p));`, you'd typically use `p[0], p[1]` etc., right?  Now `T` happens to be a pointer type, does that change anything?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp It does point to the first element of an array of 3 elements. That element is a pointer (but in general the element it may or may not be a pointer).   I don't find "double pointer" to be a very useful terminology. Pointers may point at pointers, and they may point at things which aren't pointers. There's no fundamental difference between those two cases.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, no, I won't because I use [] only with the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Oli, You only have space for two  elements, therefore you cannot do:

```
*(ret+2) = xxx;
```

as this is writing to that "third" element, which does not exist. You could allocate for three:

```
char **ret = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
```

*As to the answer to your question...*

> Do I need *(ret + 2) = "\0"; Or should it be *(ret + 2) = NULL;?

... given that you've allocated the right amount of space

*then I would use...*

```
*(ret+2) = NULL
```

*... for this reason:*

as NULL represents the value of a pointer as zero and "\0" does not, but in fact (is a literal that) points to some address which is not NULL, but contains a char that has the value zero.

Comment: and where is the answer to my question?

Comment: It's very clear, assuming that you use 3 elements, use *(ret+2) = NULL, for the reason stated (right at the end).

Comment: `then I would use:` - for what reason?

Comment: Captain Capslock reporting for service

Comment: Alexander, you are returning a pointer to an array of pointers. When you return a pointer, it "more than often" implies that one is working with arrays (albeit a horrible interface), therefore it seems that you want to use the value NULL for a sentinel (to an array of pointers), and the value NULL represents that sentinel better than the literal, as the value of the literal is not zero

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I thought it was obvious. Hopefully it is now.